# Dropdown list with case clause

Tags: grails

how can I make the following function to execute everytime I click on the drodown list

```
<g:select name="book" from="${['First', 'Second', 'for passwords']}"
            onchange="swapFieldsets(this, '#sa-email', '#sa-password')"

               />
```

the function swapFieldsSets only works once

Answer (score 1):

`onChange` will only fire if the value of the `select` element changes (HTML doesn't have "dropdowns"). If you want something to happen when clicking on the `select` element, use `onClick`.